# Firestore Query For Non Existing Key of a Map

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am aware that it is possible to do null queries, for a field that has a null value.

In my case, I have documents containing a Map and I want to query all these that do not contain a given key. In my case, this key is a string formatted date.

I did try to do this with the following code but it is not working. Instead it **fetches all documents**:

```
  Stream<List<Employee>> availableEmployeesForGivenDesignation(
      String designation, DateTime date) {
    // in firstore the keys of a map are Strings, thus I have to change DateTime to String
    var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    String formatedDate = formatter.format(date);
    //todo check why I am getting with null also the false employees
    return _employeeCollection
        .where('designations', arrayContains: designation)
        .where('busy_map.$formatedDate', isEqualTo: null) 
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents
          .map((doc) => Employee.fromEntity(EmployeeEntity.fromSnapshot(doc)))
          .toList();
    });
  }
```

To my understanding, I am querying on a map key and for some documents this key (date) does not always exist. This is why I tried to fetch these documents that return null on this case.

Database structure:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer...

I had to change the following line to:

`.where('busy_map.$formatedDate', isNull: true)`

So instead of using `isEqual` use `isNull`